# Creating reply with previous recipients in CC

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to take all the people that were sent selected email and move them to the CC line and populate two new recipients.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ReplyalMSG()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply
    Dim olRecip As Recipient ' Add Recipient
    
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Set olReply = olItem.replyall
        'Set olRecip = olReply.Recip.Add("Joesmith@gmail.com")
        'olRecip.Type = olCC
        olReply.HTMLBody = "Hi, This customer would like to request a pickup on  " & Format(Date + 1,  "dddd, mmm d yyyy") & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
        olReply.Display
    
        'olReply.Send
    Next olItem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`MailItem.ReplyAll` will populate all the recipients, you just need to reset their types - loop through all recipients in `olReply.Recipient`s collection and set their type to `olCC`. You can then call `olReply.Recipients.Add` twice to add two new recipients.

```
for each recip in olReply.Recipient
  recip.Type = olCC
next
olReply.Recipients.Add "user1@gmail.com"
olReply.Recipients.Add "user2@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Im thank full for the help!  How would I integrate that into the existing code ?   Apologies Im very new. Thanks

Comment: I tried to copy and paste the new code to see if I had it correct, but it could not get it to fit, to many characters.

Comment: @FalconWing1813 Edit the question to add new code.

Comment: Sub ReplyalMSG()
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply
Dim olRecip As Recipient ' Add Recipient

    For each recip in olReply.Recipient
      recuip.Type = olCC
    next
    olReply.Recipients.Add "user1@gmail.com"
    olReply.Recipients.Add "user2@gmail.com"

    
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Set olReply = olItem.replyall
        olReply.HTMLBody = "Hi, This customer would like to request a plant pickup on  " & Format(Date + 1, "dddd, mmm d yyyy") & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
 olReply.Display
Next olItem
End Sub

Comment: It looks terrible. My Apologies guys!

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77312132/edit) the question.

Comment: There was a type in my code ( recuip instead of recip). Try again. You also used that code at the very beginning - it needs to be placed instead of the two commented out lines after you set  olReply variable.